# is there a correct way to plot this white pixel?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pixel

iam a beginner at python and image processing etc. I want to plot this white pixel. as i know the pixel color identifier for black is 0 and for white is 255. here's the image that i want to plot:

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDvuH.png)

i try to print out the image ndarray with these following command:

```
#importing module
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

#load image
img = cv2.imread('thin.png')

#image to nd.array
arr0 = np.array(img)

#finding white pixel
arr1 = np.where(arr0 == 255)


#indexing tuple, the printout arr1 is tuple with dtype=int64
tuple1 = arr1[0]
tuple2 = arr1[1]
tuple3 = arr1[2]

#defining x and y axis
x = np.array(tuple1)
y = np.array(tuple2)
z = np.array(tuple3)

plot = plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

this is what i get..

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7UyU.png)

i think it's very noisy but i dont have a clue. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some confusion in the dimensions of you array `arr0`. I think you should look at the *indices* of the white pixels:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load image
img = cv2.imread('thin.png')

#image to nd.array
arr0 = np.array(img)

height, width, _ = arr0.shape

x = range(width)
y = [height - np.argwhere(arr0[:, i, 0]==255).mean() for i in x]    # "height -" to reverse the y-axis

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Note: taking the `mean` because a vertical line can have more than one white pixel (also some won't have any, see picture below)

Output:

[image]

Comment: sir, thank you very much. i am beginner and dont know where to learn that logical (x,y) concept. that mean and [:,i,0] concept, any suggestion for me? i want to learn!!

Comment: The [official numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html) is a good place to start. There are countless resources if you want to gather practical experiences (e.g. [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/python?filters%5Bsubdomains%5D%5B%5D=numpy) has some numpy problems). And of course stackoverflow for specific questions ;-)

Comment: thank you very much, i'll start to learn more!